# How to only define hook_menu path to certain URL

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

Consider this simple implementation of hook_menu()

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function helloworld_menu() {
  $items['hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hello world!',
    'page callback' => 'helloworld_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback for /hello.
 */
function helloworld_page() {
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

This code work when I visit **example.com/hello**, but so does when I append extra argument to the url like **example.com/hello/world**. How do I only define the **example.com/hello** only without getting all these 'derivative' URL defined as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) docs:

> When path 'abc/def' is requested, no further path components are in
>   the request, and no additional arguments are passed to the callback
>   function (so $ghi and $jkl would take the default values as defined in
>   the function signature). When 'abc/def/123/foo' is requested, $ghi
>   will be '123' and $jkl will be 'foo'. Note that this automatic passing
>   of optional path arguments applies only to page and theme callback
>   functions.

In other words, it's a feature of the Drupal menu routing system to accept additional path components.

If you're looking to try to circumvent this, you can use an `access callback` function to enforce your sole path:

```
/**
 * implements hook_menu().
 */
function helloworld_menu() {
  $items['hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hello world!',
    'page callback' => 'helloworld_page',
    'access callback' => 'helloworld_callback',
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback for /hello.
 */
function helloworld_page() {
  return "Hello World!";
}

/**
 * Access callback for /hello. 403 on addition path components.
 */
function helloworld_callback() {
  return (request_path() == 'hello');
}
```

Comment: Being pedantic, it'd be more accurate to serve a 404 here - since the URI isn't supposed to exist, a 403 isn't technically the right response. That can be accomplished in various ways in the page callback itself by checking `func_get_args()` or the `request_path()` and simply using `return MENU_NOT_FOUND;` or adding `drupal_not_found()` when the condition matches